# Remote Desktop will connect but not display window

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

I'm having a strange issue with Remote Desktop on a particular server running Windows Server 2003. It seems to connect fine but just when you would expect it to launch the window it goes back to the initial screen where you enter the computer name.
I can connect to several other servers so its not a local issue. There are no messages in the event log that would give any clues.

Comment: So before you get an opportunity to login? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Does it fail the first time, and the second time connect?

Comment: It returns to the rdp window and you never actually see a desktop? Or you see a desktop and then it drops back to the rdp? And you know the user and password are enabled for that particular machine, and the port is open through the firewall?

Comment: @JMK Yes before I get a chance to log in, no errors

Comment: @Dave Rook No it fails every time

Comment: @datatoo Never see the desktop. Don't think its firewall, all other servers that I can connect to are set up the same way

Comment: it could be a number of things. Are you using a computer name or ip address? There may not be name resolution. To not see a desktop display means you never get that far even, so it isn't authentication, but the port, or finding the machine. So make sure and check the firewall anyway

Comment: Name resolution is fine, I tried with the IP as well just to make sure. Double checked the firewall also and its not this

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx), a remote administration tool. Or [Logmein](http://www.logmein.com) app.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer RDP