# RDP works to any host other than the VPN Host

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, remote-desktop, openvpn

Dont think this is a duplicate question, lots of similar ones but none exactly the same.

Setup:
Win7 "Home Server", hosts OpenVPN server, listens on 443.
XP and 7 Boxes on the LAN
Remote:
Win8 client

The remote unit can connect to the VPN fine, access internal resources, RDP to other hosts in the network, but can only partially connect to the VPN host. It opens the connection, authenticates fine, opens the RDP window but no frames are sent. A minute later the connection closes.

Any idea as to what I need to do to make the video stream work?

Comment: Sounds like a possible firewall problem to me. Maybe the VPN box is filtering the inbound access on port 3389?

Comment: Would that not block it for all hosts, not just the VPN server?
Found another user with the same issue http://superuser.com/questions/454307/remote-desktop-will-connect-but-not-display-window

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so new server installed a few weeks ago and it was time to migrate the VPN. Same problem on the new box.

Then the answer hit me, and I began banging my head on the wall at the stupidity of not seeing it before.

Remote: 192.43 /16
Host: 192.168.2 /24
VPN: 10.8.0 /24

When opening the RDP connection I was connecting to 192.168.2.x when I should have been using the VPN address for the same machine, 10.8.0.1. *plants face on desk*

Im assuming it was creating a routing loop, or the RDP image packets werent able to navigate the last hop correctly. Either way its fixed now.